# trying to add image source but i'm getting text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace some text for a dynamically added table with icons instead , but i keep getting the url of the icons and not the image source

This is existing

```
by_cell.innerHTML = (make_it_bold ? "<b>" : "") + franchiseDatabase['fid_' + this_fid].name + (make_it_bold ? "</b>" : "");
```

I want to replace this text that is added with an image from the database instead , so i tried this , but it returns the url link in text form

```
by_cell.innerHTML = franchiseDatabase['fid_' + this_fid].icon;
```

how can i get the src of the icon to display instead of the text image path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
by_cell.innerHTML = "<img src='" + franchiseDatabase['fid_' + this_fid].icon + "' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you need to wrap the url in an image tag, so if your current javascript is outputting the just the url something like this should work

```
by_cell.innerHTML = '<img src="' + franchiseDatabase['fid_' + this_fid].icon + '" alt="image info" />';
```